# Index Out of Range When Deleting From Firebase and UITableView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a problem that when I try to delete a row from a table, my app crashes and throws an index out of range error. The data deletes fine from the firebase database and the table, but it still throws the error.

The database is designed to store playlists, and each playlist has a dictionary of keys to the name of the song. Here is my firebase structure:[image]

And below is the swift code (line where error is occurring has a comment)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let song = songs[indexPath.row]
    var songKey = ""
    if(editingStyle == .delete){
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Playlists/\(playlist!)")
        ref.observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in
            let someData = snapshot.value! as! [String: String]
            for data in someData {
                if(data.value == song){
                    songKey = data.key
                    break
                }
            }
            ref.child(songKey).removeValue()
            self.songs.remove(at: indexPath.row) //error on this line
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try without reloading tableview

Comment: @SPatel still crashes, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: try batch update api

Comment: where would i insert that command?

Comment: self.songs.remove(at: indexPath.row) //error on this line
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Could you elaborate further? Swift doesn't recognize this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should do is take another approach - handle the delete operation within its completion handler. This way you will make sure your data will be consistent. Because what happens if there is an error on your Firebase call? You have to handle this case as well. So do something like this and see what happens:

```
ref.child(songKey).removeValue { [weak self] error, _ in 
    if let error = error {
        print("There was an error: ", error)
        return
    }
    self?.songs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

What I think is happening here is that your code enters an infinite loop - you use observe on your `playlists` then you delete. So `observe`'s completion handler is called again and `delete` is called again. After you deleted the item at this index, the index cannot be found on your array anymore. So just get your playlists from the database without observing any further changes.

In this case try using `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: same behavior, deletes from database but index out of range at same line

Comment: Can you print something for me: `print("songs count: \(songs.count) | selected row index: \(indexPath.row)")`

Comment: I put the print statement above the line throwing the error, console printed: songs count: Optional(3) | selected row index: 2                                                            
songs count: Optional(2) | selected row index: 2

Comment: Okay, so there is your answer: you are trying to delete third of 2 songs. Did you remove this line: `self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`?

Comment: I did delete that line as you suggested before, and I was still getting the error

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I have an idea and a question. 1.) Would observeSingleEvent() be suitable? 2.) How can I get data from the database without observing? Very new to firebase so sorry if these questions are simple

Comment: Just updated my answer again so it includes `observeSingleEvent `. Yes, give it a try.

Comment: Thank you! The error has been fixed! I now have some weird behavior where multiple table views are being pushed on that contain deleted songs, but I think that's because I don't delete the item from the table view. It isn't reset until the data is pulled again